# How to host my ASP.Net admin panel without buying a domain?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xml, host

I'm very new to web development but I will try to explain my question as best as I can.

I am making a basic admin panel program in C#. The admin panel will pass the data to android SQLite database using XML files, so XML file will be generated whenever admin updates data, and then it'll send the data to mobile phone.

Developing is all done but I need to host the admin panel in order to give XML links to my mobile app developer so she can create XML parser class or something. (please bear with me, I'm very new to programming). Anyway, I have no idea how to host it!

I've done some Googling but they all saying I need to buy domain name. I need to host it without buying domain.

Hope that's clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're simply pushing data to the service on the phone, then you shouldn't need a domain name or a hosting service.  Simply run the Admin Panel from a machine that has access to the internet - it should connect to the service on the phone just fine.  Having said that, domain's are dirt cheap....

Comment: Thanks Tim, Yes, I just want to push data to mobile phone. This is a school project and tutor said can host it without buying domain but just don't know how. I can run the program in Firefox using IIS with no internet connection (I think)but I need the admin panel to be live so I can give the XML links to mobile developer.

Comment: Oh, and it is kind of mandatory that we have to make our admin panel live without buying the domain. I'm using XML files instead of web service but by simply running my program (firefox) from my laptop will connect to the service on the mobile? in other words, it'll push the updated data to mobile phone?? Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a very good hosting and you don't mind about the domain name definitely try microsoft azure it is very quality server and free when you don't want to use your domain name. I mean your address would be yourdomain.microsoftazure.com instead of yourdomain.com. It is always free and you can have an sql server database free for first year. however you should put a credit card number that only used for identification and microsoft never charge you for that.
See the site below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thanks user2989995! Sorry for the late reply coz I'm in NZ time. One of my classmate did it and his domain name is "http://admin.hisdomainname.easyoffice.co.nz/" so easyoffice is some kind of microsoft azure? I already have my SQL server so I don't need the free one. Anyway, I'll try both and will let you know as soon as I can! Thanks a lot~

Comment: I've just checked out the link but I only can see one month free trial 'Sign-up for free and get $250 to spend on all Azure services'. Is this the one you are talking about? Thanks~

Comment: No, Azure provide alot of services that you must pay to use. For using them you have to pay and you have $250 to spend first month as trial. But if you only want to use website service and use shared service, you can have 10 website free forever

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the quick reply but I don't really know which https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/websites/ is this the one I should go for? Thanks~

Comment: See the link, it explains how publish. just notice that you must select shared website as it is free one. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I actually was reading it, but I already have created my website with ASP.Net Empty Web Application and I have Visual Studio 2012 installed in my laptop. I didn't use MVC 4 but do I need to use MCV4? Thanks for replying once again~

Comment: Not at all. The publish utility is same and doesn't matter if you use MVC or webform

Comment: Thanks a lot! looks like it's gonna work just fine! Thank for for your time for answering my question~